# check if xml document contains element with a certain id attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to find out if a document has a node with a certain id attribute.

I iterate over a list of nodes and for each node I need to check whether a second document contains an element with the same id and then do something.

my approach was:

```
<xsl:variable name="variableOfDocument" select="doc(iri-to-uri('somedocument.xml'))/>

<!-- check, whether somewhere in the document, there is an element with the same id as the element currently matched -->
<xsl:if test="$variableOfDocument//*[text()[contains(.,$currentId)]]">
<!-- do something -->
</xsl:if>
```

but that doesnt work - it doesnt find the matches. How do I need to put the xpath? (i'm using xslt 2.0)

Comment: Please show all input documents and a complete XSLT stylesheet: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

Since my document has only elements with attributs and no text-nodes, I needed to put it like this:

```
<xsl:if test="$currCompFile//*/node()/@id = $curID"/>
```

Checks, whether any of the id-attributes in $currCompFile match the value of the $curID.